# Probability for Player P3 winning

Tags: probability, probability-theory, conditional-probability

I have 10 players in a pool with names repeating. I need to draw 3 winners from the pool and each player can't have more than 5 entries in the pool.
Ex: [P0, P1, P2, P2, P3, P3, P3, P3, P3, P4, P4, P5]
What is the probability for P3 to win (at least once in 3 draws) in the below cases.

1. Draw a winner without taking the winner entries out of the pool for the next draw. If we pick an already winner again then we re-draw until a new player is a winner.
2. Draw a winner and remove all the entries of the winner from the pool and re-draw for second winner and so on.

In which scenario P3 has more probability to win?

Comment: Net result of both methods is same.

Comment: Please see [this article on MathSE protocol](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33190/how-to-avoid-downvotes-for-beginners-questions/33236#33236).
As onerous as the article may appear to you, it provides a defense mechanism against the MathSE forum being used as a *do my homework* forum.  In particular, please see the **Edit-Tools** section of the article, and the portion of the article that discusses *showing work*.